# Android M (preview) App Standby

Tags: android-emulator, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm trying to put an app in standby mode. I'm using an emulator running Android API 23 (Revision 1). I am not able to put the app in standby by following the steps listed in the official docs:

- adb shell dumpsys battery unplug
- adb shell am set-inactive  true

When I test if the app is actually in standby using `adb shell am get-inactive <packageName>` I always obtain the following result "Idle=false". I've also locked the screen before executing the commands listed above but the result is always the same "Idle=false".
Is anyone else experiencing the same behavior?

Comment: EDIT: See answer below.

Comment: Are you turning the screen off before attempting to put the app into app standby mode? 

You can also just test to see if you can enter idle mode at all.
After "unplugging the battery" via `adb shell dumpsys battery unplug`, try triggering idle mode by running `adb shell dumpsys deviceidle step` until the device enters idle mode, or run `adb shell dumpsys deviceidle force-idle`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in the emulator and you can't set an app in idle mode using adb commands. You need to use a real device.

Comment: Edit: sorry, I don't have experience with the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into the same thing. It turns out if the package has a widget currently on the launcher screen, it gets prevented from going into standby mode, even with the adb command. Remove the widget and toggling inactive mode should work. You can also set an app into app standby by going to developer settings, scroll all the way to the bottom and click on "inactive apps" and then you can toggle it there (may have to long hold the app).

EDIT: You also need to have the device unplugged or pretend unplug it with: adb shell dumpsys battery unplug

Comment: I also tried to put the app in stanby from the "Inactive apps" menu but, after touching the app (even after unplugging the emulator), I always see the app as active... also the emulator seems to freeze. The app doesn't have any widget associated.

Comment: Did you try long pressing it?

Comment: @Flyview, "inactivate apps" in developer setting worked. I could not find this info any other place over the net. Where did you find this?

Comment: @Tomcat I originally found the information here when I was running into issues. http://kjlee5435.blogspot.ca/2015/08/new-power-saving-mode-in-android-m.html